# Are the emissions to power electric cars really better for the environment than the emissions from petrol cars?

Tags: electric-machine

In my country most of the electricity is generated by coal which is then in turn used to power electric cars, which I don’t think is to good for the atmosphere, is there any prof that this is better for the atmosphere than the emissions from a petrol engines in the majority of cars ?

Comment: Depends on how clean the coal tower precipitators do their job. or if they have any.  These employ very high power HVDC and vibration cleaners in the stack.

Comment: Well, power plants are don't move and can be huge so could have less design concessions towards emission control, whereas cars have to be able to move their own weight. Just look at how dirty tiny 2 stroke motorcycle engines are compared to a car's 4-stroke engine.

Comment: If you think the coal is bad, don't look at what it takes to make those high end batteries. Just mining the precious metals alone may offset the lifetime of the vehicle in carbon emissions.

Comment: @RonBeyer Batteries used in EVs don't use precious metals.  You may be thinking fuel cells, which tend to use platinum.

Comment: Still, mining and refining high purity lithium has got to require a ton of energy.

Comment: @DKNguyen The name is somewhat misleading, since by mass a lithium ion battery is only 1 or 2 % lithium.  The majority of mass of an automotive battery is similar stuff to other automotive parts (aluminum, carbon, iron and copper) since the electrolyte has more or less negligible mass.

Comment: @user1850479 interesting. I thought there was as much lithium as there is lead in a lead acid battery

Comment: Ron, please try to use at least a little bit of critical thinking skill. Energy costs money. The cost of a battery sets an UPPER LIMIT on how much energy may be used to make it. Otherwise people would go out of business making batteries because they would spend more on energy making the battery than they could recoup when it is sold.

Comment: @DKNguyen Lead is about 21 times more dense than lithium, so if you need an equal number of atoms, the lead is 21 times more massive.  For that reason there is less lithium in a Tesla then there is lead in a normal car's 12v battery.

Comment: Fedex requires you to list the amount of lithium in each battery when shipping. They use this formula: 0.3 grams * Ah/cell * Number_of_cells. So a 3 Ah 18650 would contain 0.3 * 3 = 0.9g of lithium. The cell weight is around 45 grams. So not much lithium on a percent basis.

Comment: However precious metals are used in the electric motors and, at present, China has a near monopoly on them.

Comment: In a lead acid battery, the electrodes are made of lead. There is not that much lead in solution. But in a lithium ion battery, neither of the electrodes is made out of lithium. All of the lithium is in solution (assuming the battery is healthy).

Comment: @Barry Rare earths are not "precious metals"  neodmium is about  $110 000 per tonne  silver is about $570/kg  so not even semi-precious.  if the price goes up enough mines outside of China will reopen.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to use permanent magnet motors for electric vehicles. Induction motors are also perfectly viable. Induction motors are mostly iron and copper and perhaps aluminum for the housing.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what vehicles you compare and what the exact breakdown of your local grid is, but in general, yes EVs tend to emit significantly less CO2 than your average car even when the grid is not particularly low carbon just because gasoline engines are pretty inefficient.  This plot shows how many MPG a gasoline car has to get to match an higher efficiency EV:

[image: EV-mileage]

https://blog.ucsusa.org/rachael-nealer/gasoline-vs-electric-global-warming-emissions-953

As you can see the numbers vary pretty widely since different parts of the USA use more or less coal/gas for power, but on average it is very hard to get a gasoline vehicle that is efficient enough to match an EV.